# Adding HTML files as part of TOCTree hierarchy in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have HTML files that I generate through some Python code, majority of these files include tables and as far as I know, the .rst format has no tables like .html does. So I want to just generate these .html files and put them in a hierarchy and display them in my TOCTree.

I know the question seems very general and pretty basic but the Sphinx documentation I [followed](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/index.html) does not answer the questions I have.

Comment: reStructuredText has markup for tables: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#tables

Comment: The content of toctree is a list of .rst files. You cannot refer to HTML files. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree